# Separar el contenido de una celda en una tabla en codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, tablas

Hola que tal? estoy intentando separar los datos de fecha y hora que están en una misma celda de una tabla, necesito que tanto la fecha y la hora se muestren en dos columnas distintas, saben si hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin tener que crear dos columnas adicionales en la base de datos para la hora de inicio y finalización?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de exportar en un excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitaría que me quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Edita, por favor, tu pregunta y añade lo que has intentado. De esta forma la comunidad podrá ayudarte. Podrías mirar también el siguiente apartado de como preguntar [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask], para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, lo quieres realizar desde la consulta (BD) o desde código?

Una idea con PHP es que cuando estes recorriendo el resultado de tu consulta y cuando creas tu td le des el formato correspondiente

```
echo '<td>'.date('d-m-Y',strtotime($res[0]->fechacreaccion)).'</td>';
```

Usando la función date
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Puedes asignar el formato que deseas, Pero es necesario conocer donde quieres hacer el separado, como creas tu tabla, usas algún plug-in para crear tu tabla?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, si efectivamente solo fue necesario hacer la discriminación desde date, muchas gracias, ahora estoy trabajando en el controlador  y las vistas para hacer los cambios, saludos.